# Application of Hahn Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a real normed vector space, $M \subset E$ a convex balanced subset with $B (0, δ) ⊂ M$ for
some $δ > 0$, and $x_0 \notin M $. Show the existence of an element $x_0' \in  E'$  such that

$x_0'(x_0) \geq \sup_{x \in M} |x_0'(x)|$

Im pretty sure I have to use  Hahn Banach here with the Minkowski functional $p_M$  but i have no idea what other function to look at to apply Hahn Banach. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Try some linear functional defined on the one-dimensional space spanned by $x_0$.

Comment: @Ruy Im not really getting any good idea yet. Havent done anything with Hahn Banach before. You are talking about a function $f: \mathbb{R}x_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ im guessing. Could you try to lead me abit more?

Comment: Yes!  Can you build such a function so that $$f(x)\leq p_M(x)?$$

Comment: @Ruy Since M is balanced we have that $p_m(x_0) > 1$ , and more generally $p_m(\lambda x_0) > \lambda$ for $\lambda > 0$. We could choose $f(\lambda x_0) = \lambda$. Is this a good decision?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Thanks @Ruy!!! Now we just extend $f$ to $F$ and use that $F(x) \leq p(x) \leq 1 = f(x_0)$  on $M$ it seems.

Comment: Given the notation you used in your question I'd call the extension $x'_0$, rather than $F$.

Comment: @Ruy yeah. One last question. How comes I dont need to use the property that the ball $B(0,\delta)$ is included in $M$? Am I missing something in above argument?

Comment: Oh nevermind. thats needed for the sublinarity of $p_M$. Thanks again for everything!

Comment: Have you already proven that $x_0'\in E'$, i.e. that $x_0'$ is continuous?

Comment: I haven't. Any hint on how to get there?

Comment: Can you estimate $$\sup_{\|x\|<\delta}|x'_0(x)|?$$

Comment: Yeah its $\leq x'(x_o) = 1 $ since M includes the $\delta$ ball

Comment: Great!  Can you now turn this into a proof that $x'_0$  is bounded on the unit ball (which is equivalent to continuity)?

Comment: I got it yeah! Thank you so much!